# how to use oauth2.0 call youtube v3 api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to use youtube v3 api to do a side project like youtube, I read the [YOUTUBE V3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation) file if I want to have CRUD and upload features must use oauth2.0, currently [Creating OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) credentials has been completed, then can also get the token smoothly.

But my problem is that the documentation does not see an example of using the oauth2.0 call api.

In the case of [Playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/playlists) just see the instructions and incomplete url

**Instructions:**

"Call the playlists.list method to retrieve the currently authenticated user's playlists. In your request, set the mine parameter's value to true. Note that a request that uses the mine parameter must be authorized using OAuth 2.0"

**URL:**
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list?part=snippet,contentDetails&mine=true

**No examples of JSON or use oauth2.0 token call API, I would like to ask if you have used or. There are examples (API request & respond)**

Thanks